# Getting name of executing tool in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I created a script in a custom ToolBox and I defined a name (here ImportTopojis):

[image]

This name is displayed when you execute the tool :

[image]

I simply want to get this name because I want to use a single Python file for multiple tools and choose the proper class to use depending on this name.

Comment: How do you want to run this tool - by importing it in `arcpy` code and then calling it? Publish any code you  have already written where you are importing the tool to execute it later.

Comment: I wrote a arcpy script and I added a tool in a ToolBox. When you create it, you have to give it a name (my first print screen). Then, I execute as a geoprocessing in ArcGIS Pro. I just want to get this name in my script so I could use it to choose wich function I have to use.
This is my only need : get this name with arcpy

Comment: Hi @PaCha, did you end up finding a solution for this one? I'm also facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 2):

When you import a toolbox:

`arcpy.ImportToolbox(r'C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\Toolbox.tbx' , 'SuperToolbox')`

It is being imported into a module:
`<module 'SuperToolbox' (built-in)>`

Now you can call any tool that is located within this toolbox (I have a script tool called `PrettyTable`:

```
>>> arcpy.SuperToolbox.PrettyTable
<function PrettyTable at 0x2152CFB0>
```

Since it is a module, you can use `dir` to get all its tools:

```
dir(arcpy.SuperToolbox)
['AddFields', 'CalculateArea', 'GetSelectedFeature', 'ListFields', 'MultiFiles', 'PrettyTable', 'Script', 'SlopeCalc', '__alias__', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', '__pathname__', 'filterlyrs', 'foo']
```

The tools within the toolbox are just module's functions. You can access function's name by using the `func_name` internal property:

```
arcpy.SuperToolbox.PrettyTable.func_name
'PrettyTable'
```

Comment: It will give me the function name of a tool in a toolbox... not the one I'm actually using, no ?

Comment: The name you specify in the "Label" is the one you will see in the toolbox when you expand it to see the tools. The "Name" field is the function name you call in `arcpy`.

Comment: Sorry but I think you don't understand... I'll take your example : you ToolBox contains a set of tools, including PrettyTable. Let's imagine they are all Python script tools. You tell me I have to use arcpy.SuperToolbox.[PrettyTable].func_name but, if a use the same script for all tools with a different behavior for each, I cannot know it's PrettyTable that is actually used as the "launching tool". In my script there is no sense to force PrettyTable than another tool because I don't know wich one called the script.

Comment: Now it is me who does not follow :D I start thinking that you use the toolbox and script tools functionality in a weird way. Why would you use the same Python module (`.py` file) for all tools within a toolbox? Each script tool is supposed to be associated with its own `.py` file. If you need to handle "if-else" logic you are better doing it with the parameters within the script tools and custom validator class.